# How to update table in one server from another server

Tags: java, plsql

I have below code for opening two files on one server and updating data from those files to another database server. I am able to open DB connection but when I am trying to update one table on DB server it is giving connection is read only not able to update table. Don't know where I am doing wrong. Please help me on this, error is below: 
[image]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class tstnew
{

    public static void main (String args[])  throws Exception
    {

FileInputStream fin,fin1;       
  int k=0;
String line,line1,s,s1,g,g1,d,d1;
        try
        {

Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

//DriverManager.registerDriver( new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
   ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.195.38:1521:ROW1", "********", "********");
 System.out.println("connected");
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

 //fin = new FileInputStream ("C:/Users/BOT2/Desktop/OGL/MC_WIth_DATA_Files.txt");
 System.out.println("1");
fin = new FileInputStream ("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/SetUp/MC_WIth_DATA_Files.txt");

 fin1 = new FileInputStream ("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/SetUp/MC_With_Empty_Files.txt");


DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fin);

BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
 System.out.println("1");
BufferedReader br2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin1));

while ((line=br1.readLine() )!= null){
  k++;
  s=line.replaceAll("[0-9_]+", "");

g=s.replaceAll("\\s+","");

if(g.equals("Baltic")){g="Baltics";}
if(g.equals("Netherlands")){g="Netherland";}
if(g.equals("SouthAfricaSubSahara")){g="SSA";}
if(g.equals("Algeria")){g="ALGERIA";}
if(g.equals("EmergingMENA")){g="EMM";}
if(g.equals("SaudiArabia")){g="Saudi Arabia";}
if(g.equals("SouthAfrica")){g="South Africa";}
if(g.equals("Slovakia")){g="slovakia";}

System.out.println(g); 

d="update ogl_table_status set status = 1 where mc_name='"+ g +"' and status=0";
stmt.executeUpdate(d);

}


  while ( (line1=br2.readLine() )!= null ){
  k++;

  s1=line1.replaceAll("[0-9_]+", "");


g1=s1.replaceAll("\\s+","");


if(g1.equals("Baltic")){g1="Baltics";}
if(g1.equals("Netherlands")){g1="Netherland";}
if(g1.equals("SouthAfricaSubSahara")){g1="SSA";}
if(g1.equals("Algeria")){g1="ALGERIA";}
if(g1.equals("EmergingMENA")){g1="EMM";}
if(g1.equals("SaudiArabia")){g1="Saudi Arabia";}
if(g1.equals("SouthAfrica")){g1="South Africa";}
if(g1.equals("Slovakia")){g1="slovakia";}

System.out.println(g1); 

d1="update ogl_table_status set status = 1 where mc_name='"+ g1 +"' and status=0";

stmt.executeUpdate(d1);

}
conn.commit();
System.out.println(k);
stmt.close();
br1.close();
br2.close();
     fin.close();
     fin1.close();
        }
        // Catches any error conditions
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Unable to read from file");
            System.exit(-1);

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: nice username and password there

Comment: I would suggest you check your db permissions - can you alter the row if you connect via a db client (eg: sqldeveloper).

Comment: Maybe because the user "azglobal_users_qc" doesn't have the privilege to update anything. Maybe when the dba's of that server gave you that user, he/she limited the insert/update/delete privileges of that user. You should call him/her. Also can you execute your sql outside of the jdbc, for example plsql developer or oracle sql developer to if there is a problem or not. (check privileges using this way)

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

> database open for read only access

Currently you can execute other than SELECT statements. 
You need to open your Oracle DB in WRITE mode as pre [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start002.htm#ADMIN11153) in order to execute UPDATE statement